# using a Python dictionary to count the frequency of words, excluding a set of "stop words" that will be read from a second file

Tags: python

Truth be told I am a novice when it comes to coding but this is my last assignment of this semester and I'm just completely stuck So basically I need to Write a Python program that reads a text file containing English words and uses a Python dictionary to count the frequency of words, excluding a set of "stop words" that will be read from a second file. Use matplotlib.pyplot to create a horizontal bar chart histogram showing the words and counts of the top 15 most frequently encountered words in the input file

I'm able to open and print out the words from both txt files and Iv made everything lower case for easier reading , removed punctuation , and separated the words in the lines.

I really just need help on iterating over the "stopwords" file with the words I pulled from the "usconst" file. I honestly have no clue on how to do that with a dictionary. Any info on the histogram would be nice also.

Here is what I have so far.

```
def main():
  
    text = open("usconst.txt" , "r")
    texts = open("stopwords.txt" , "r")
    
  

    
   #loop through each line of the file for us const
    
    line_count = 1
    d = dict()
   
        # us const 
    for line in text:
      print("line{} : is {}".format(line_count , line))
      line_count += 1
      line = line.translate(line.maketrans("","",string.punctuation))
      line = line.lower()
      words = line.split()
      print("words =" , words , "\n")
      
      # stop words 
    for line in texts:
      line_count += 1
      line = line.lower()
      line = line.translate(line.maketrans("","",string.punctuation))
      words = line.split()
      
      
      
    for word in words:
        if word in d:
                print("word--{}-- is already in dictionary, its value is {}".format(word , d[word])) 
        else:
            d[word] = 42
```

Comment: OK, but you aren't keeping the word lists anywhere.  You need to ACCUMULATE the words you're splitting into one big list, and you need to use a separate list for the two loops.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (untested because I don't have your lists):

```
def main():
  
    text = open("usconst.txt" , "r")
    texts = open("stopwords.txt" , "r")
    
    line_count = 1
   
    # us const 
    uswords = []
    for line in text:
      print("line{} : is {}".format(line_count , line))
      line_count += 1
      line = line.translate(line.maketrans("","",string.punctuation))
      line = line.lower()
      uswords.extend( line.split() )
    print("uswords =" , uswords , "\n")
      
      # stop words
    stopwords = [] 
    for line in texts:
      line_count += 1
      line = line.lower()
      line = line.translate(line.maketrans("","",string.punctuation))
      stopwords.extend( line.split())

    counts = {}      
    for word in uswords:
        if word in stopwords:
            continue
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1
    print( counts )
```

There are smarter ways to do some of that, but this keeps your basic philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize a set of stop-words, and a dict of word counts from your text after normalizing them (removing punctuation, lowercase, etc).

Then you can sum the values of the dict for words which are not in the stop-words set.

I used parts of your code but in the approach I detailed above.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def normalize(line):
    line = line.lower()
    return line.translate(line.maketrans("","",string.punctuation))   

# create a normalized stop-word set
stop_words = set()
with open("stopwords.txt" , "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    stop_words.update(normalize(line).split())

# create normalized-words count dictionary
words_count = defaultdict(int)
with open("usconst.txt" , "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    for w in normalize(line).split():
      words_count[w] += 1

# list by most frequent words which are not stop-words
sorted([k,v for k,v in words_count.items() if k not in stop_words], reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
```